# TinyMCE popups not loading when using S3 and setting document.domain

Tags: django, amazon-s3, tinymce, amazon-cloudfront, django-tinymce

My main domain is 'btaylorweb.com'. I have a subdomain 'static.btaylorweb.com' that uses a CNAME to point to my CloudFront URL.

TinyMCE is loading just fine from S3, however, my popups are blank. I've set the domain as such:

```
document.domain = 'btaylorweb.com';
```

in tiny_mce_popup.js and in tiny_mce.js, but that's still not working. Can anyone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: please post your full tinymce initialization! which tinymce version are you using?

Comment: I'm ot overly familiar with S3 and more importantly "cross-domain" issues however given the majority of popups, including plugins, involve additional JavaScript files to *tiny_mce_popup.js* they may be the cause of your problem.

 Have you tried checking with something like Firebug in the popup windows (assuming they even appear) to see if the JS files are loading?

Comment: Hi guys. I've taken the CloudFront distribution for that project offline, but I did verify that the JavaScript files for the popup were loading. I've found a workaround for this issue for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up leveraging the Image plugin in DjangoCMS, which can be used in conjunction with django-storages to push files directly to the S3 bucket. It works, but the Image plugin isn't quite as nice as seeing the images inline with the rest of the content.